# Pandas: How to merge all rows into a single row?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, txt

I have the following dataframe:

```
  text
1 "abc" 
2 "def" 
3 "ghi"
4 "jkl"
```

How can I merge these rows into a dataframe with a single row like the following one?

```
  text 
1 "abc, def, ghi, jkl"
```

Comma separation is not a must but all the values should be in a single row. The values can also be stored in a comma separated list of strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': [', '.join(df['text'].str.strip('"').tolist())]})
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                 text
0  abc, def, ghi, jkl
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the list of values, use `to_list`:

```
sr = pd.Series(', '.join(df['text'].to_list()), name='text')

# OR

df = pd.DataFrame([', '.join(df['text'].to_list())], columns=['text'])
```

Output:

```
>>> sr
0    abc, def, ghi, jkl
Name: text, dtype: object

>>> df
                 text
0  abc, def, ghi, jkl
```